# VBScript:Verifying if printer share exists

Tags: windows, networking, printing, vbscript

Is there a way to determine in VBScript, if a print share is in existence on a print server? The idea is to remove the connection to that printer in the event the share is removed from the server.

A file share is a matter if checking for an existing folder, but what about a print share?

Comment: I'd suggest using Group Policy Preferences to manage printer mappings instead of VBScripts.

Comment: We already do, but using GPP must be abandoned for printer policy purposes. We have around 1000 printers in this particular facility and it slows Logins considerably (5-6min). So scripting is necessary to process printer policy post login.

Answer (score 1):

The following VBScript uses WMI to connect to the PC and list all of the print queues on your local Windows machine. To query a remote machine, just type that machine's name in place of the `.` in the `strComputer` variable.

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colPrinters = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Printer")

For Each objPrinter in colPrinters
    If objPrinter.Attributes And 64 Then 
        strPrinterType = "Local"
    Else
        strPrinterType = "Network"
    End If
    Wscript.Echo objPrinter.Name & " -- " & strPrinterType
Next
```

To remove a printer from a machine use something like:

```
Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
objNet.RemovePrinterConnection "\\SERVER\Printer"
```

For more info see [MS TechNet: Managing Network Printers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156601.aspx).

Bear in mind that some printers may be installed at the system level, and available to all users all the time, but on client PCs queues might only be installed in the user's profile and only available to their account, while they're logged in.